# Getting floated image to align top left

Tags: html, css, sass

I have banner that needs to have an image aligned to the left and full height from top to bottom. To the right of the Image is an H1 with a Tab-selection Div, and below that is Text/Content Div. The Image is set to the height and width I want through WordPress.

Here's an image of what i'm going for:

[image]

I can somewhat get what I want by floating left on the image to get the Div Text to go to the right.

But my biggest problem is that I can't get my image to align top left of the banner properly. I had to use -142px margin left and -281px margin-top just to get it to look like it was, but on bigger screens I want that image to always stay left and consistent. It doesn't stay left on bigger screen sizes.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's the code for the Image Div:
(image dimensions set on WordPress as 641 width x 716 height)

```
  margin-left: -142px; 
  margin-top: -281px;
  float:left;
  max-width:103%;
  left:0;
  display:inline-block;
  top:0;
  position:relative;
```

The damn image just stays at the bottom. I made sure that the H1 element wasn't displayed as Block in case it was blocking the Image from moving up.

There is a wrapper around the Div Image and Div Text that I used this code:

```
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
```

When I look through Chrome inspector, the width of the Image and Text wrapper doesn't go across the Banner section all the way either. Is this wrapper just my problem? Or is it how I'm targeting the image?

Also just to clarify: I'm trying to code this banner on WordPress so there is pretty limited HTML changes that I can make.

Thanks!! I've been looking everywhere on SO and Google and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Maybe my problem is too specific? I'd really appreciate the help. I'd also be happy to give more examples / post more code if it helps.

Comment: can you provide the your html code

Comment: can you link to the site?  it'll be a lot easier to provide the correct answer if we can see and inspect the entire markup and CSS in use.

Comment: `position:absolute` to your image will place it on top-left. `position:relative` can't.

Comment: also, remove `margin-left`, `margin-top` and `float:left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give css to `<img>`

```
img{
   height:100%;
   max-height:100%;
   width:auto;
}
```

may be this should work or if not then just post your html css i can help more from that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of what I did that may help you out some. There's no need to use the `float` property for this. Just specify the `width` property to whatever size you want it to be based on screen size.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/500/any);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
}

header .header_img_left {
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header_img_left">
            
            </div>
        </header>
 </body>
</html>
```